# .NET ClaimsIdentity to JWT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm tying to determine the best practice for converting the `Claims` list in the .NET `ClaimsIdentity` to a JSON Web Token (https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt). If I try to use the `Claims` list directly in `JsonWebToken.Encode()` I get a circular reference exception.

My first thought was to convert it into a `Dictionary<string,object>`. The challenge is to convert the string `Claim.Value` to the appropriate type instance. It doesn't look like there's any good way to use the `ClaimValueTypes` indications to convert the `Value` to the appropriate instances, barring a big ugly case statement.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Big ugly case / if statement it is. I just implemented the bare minimum and will add cases as needed. Unfortunately, there's no `Decimal` type in the `ClaimValueTypes`

```
public static class ClaimExtensions
{
    public static object ValueAsValueType(this Claim claim)
    {
        switch (claim.ValueType)
        {
            case ClaimValueTypes.Double:
                return double.Parse(claim.Value);
            case ClaimValueTypes.String:
                return claim.Value;
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unhandled ClaimValueType {0} in ClaimExtensions.ValueAsValueType()", claim.ValueType));
        }
    }

    public static List<Claim> ToClaims(this Dictionary<string, object> payload)
    {
        return payload.Select(x =>
        {
            string valueType;
            var value = x.Value;

            if (x.Value is double || x.Value is decimal)
                valueType = ClaimValueTypes.Double;
            else if (x.Value is string)
                valueType = ClaimValueTypes.String;
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unhandled type of Claim Value {0} in ClaimExtensions.ToClaims()", value.GetType()));

            return new Claim(x.Key, x.Value.ToString(), valueType);
        }).ToList();

    } 
}
```

Comment: You should be able to create your own ClaimValueTypes though.